# subprocess command inside airflow fails to find executable and associated file

Tags: sql-server, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have this task in airflow:

```
def bcp_in(**kwargs):
    files = []
    for file in glob.glob(Variable.get("temp_directory") + "FILEGROUP1/FILE*.csv"):
        files.append(file)
    print("LOCAL FILES {}".format(files))
    for file in files:
        print('Importing File {}'.format(file))
        cmd = '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp db1.dbo.table1 IN "{file}" -F2  -Utheuser -Pmypassword -Sserver1 -t"~" -c'.format(file=file)
        print(subprocess.check_output(cmd))


BCP_Import_Files = PythonOperator(
    task_id='BCP_Import_Files_to_DB3_Staging',
    python_callable=bcp_in,
    dag=dag
)
```

assuming the user that airflow is running under is `airflow`, I tested the bcp under that user in a command prompt with no difficulties.

however, when I run this under normal airflow operations, the task fails with this error:

```
2020-01-27 20:18:28,731] {taskinstance.py:1051} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp db1.dbo.table1 IN "file1" -F2  -Utheuser -Pmypassword -Sserver1 -t"~" -c': '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp db1.dbo.table1 IN "file1" -F2  -Utheuser -Pmypassword -Sserver1 -t"~" -c'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 926, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/dags/BCP_TEST_NOT_PROD.py", line 30, in bcp_in
    print(subprocess.check_output(cmd))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp db1.dbo.table1 IN "file1" -F2  -Utheuser -Pmypassword -Sserver1 -t"~" -c': '/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp db1.dbo.table1 IN "file1.csv" -F2  -Utheuser -Pmypassword -Sserver1 -t"~" -c'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who run into the same problem.

Sub-process must have the segment `shell=True` as part of the call in order to run any sort of command that has parameters, or is passed to the sub-process command via string or string injection. Example:

```
print(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True))
```

If you are going to ONLY pass the direct command executable (i.e. shell script, or file.sh) then you can pass it without the shell. Example:

```
print(subprocess.check_output('path/to/exe.sh'))
```

I hope this helps someone else.